# go install: add non-source files to built package

Tags: file, go, build, installation, external

My $GOPATH looks like this:

```
src/
  mypkg/
    source.go
    config.txt
bin/
  mypkg
pkg/
  somestuff/
```

When I build my package with `go install` (that builds and places the executable in `bin`), I'd like `config.txt` to be copied in that folder together with the executable. Is there a way to do so?

Sorry if I didn't find a way that may look obvious to you, but I'm new to programming, especially to Go.

Comment: Not using `go install`.  Perhaps you want a makefile and/or build script?

Comment: Really is there no way with Go install? Is it only limited to source files? @Kaedys

Comment: `go install` is pretty close to identical to `go build`, except that it places the binary in `$GOPATH/bin` (instead of the local directory) and caches the compiled versions of non-main packages in `$GOPATH/pkg` (instead of discarding them).  To my knowledge, it has no functionality to handle anything aside from the source files and the resulting artifacts.

Comment: Okay, so should a simple sh script that `go build`s and copies the files do the job? @Kaedys

Comment: You can even use `go install` and copy the file, but ya, either will work.  A `makefile` will probably be more extensible, but if all you need is to copy the config file, a simple shell script should do just fine.

Comment: Advantage of using `go install` even in the script, by the way, is that if you have a large code base with lots of non-main packages, you won't have to recompile them on each build.  It'll use the cached versions unless that package's source files have changed since last build.

Comment: Thank you very much. But, is there a way to set `go install` to build **only a certain package** in a folder different than $GOPATH/bin? @Kaedys

Comment: No, `go install` always installs to `$GOPATH/bin`.  You could change your `$GOPATH` for that script, but that isn't advisable.  That said, what do you mean by installing only a certain package, though?  `go install` places the compiled binary in `$GOPATH/bin`.  No packages get placed there (their compiled version is cached in `$GOPATH/pkg` instead).  By definition, `go install` only installs a `main` package, just as `go build` only builds a `main` package.

Comment: I'm sorry, by "only a certain package" I meant "only a folder in $GOPATH/src". Anyway thanks for your help @Kaedys.

Comment: @altermetax: you use `go install import/path` to install a specific package.

Comment: @Kaedys: you use `GOBIN` to set the destination of `go install` binaries.

Comment: I know about `GOBIN`, but that way I should write a script that sets `GOBIN` and then `go install`s. Is that recommended? @JimB

Comment: That's fine. You can move the binary after install too, it's the same result.

Comment: @JimB I thought usage of `GOBIN` was discouraged?

Comment: @Kaedys: why? it just changes where the final binary is placed, so there not much it could interfere with.

Comment: Hmm, ya, you're right, I was thinking about `$GOROOT`, not `$GOBIN`

Answer (score 1):

You can "pack" the static files (text, images etc.) by including it into a .go file (usually automatically generated) and then compiling it into the stand-alone binary.  You can do it by using https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/godoc/static/makestatic.go or with https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata. See http://blog.ralch.com/tutorial/golang-embedded-resources/ for more information and examples.

Comment: go-bindata can now be found at https://github.com/go-bindata/go-bindata